# What is the difference between LIKE and AS SELECT * FROM in duplicating a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to practice sql using w3resource's sample activities. They gave an answer to that activity but they do not have further explanation on to why they used a specific script, and I want to know what would be the difference when I would do this.

> 3. Write a SQL statement to create the structure of a table dup_countries similar to countries.
>    Answer:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dup_countries LIKE countries;
```

Output:

```
mysql> DESC dup_countries;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| COUNTRY_ID   | varchar(2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COUNTRY_NAME | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REGION_ID    | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

> 4. Write a SQL statement to create a duplicate copy of countries table including structure and data by name dup_countries.

Answer:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dup_countries AS SELECT * FROM  countries;
```

Output:

```
mysql> DESC dup_countries;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| COUNTRY_ID   | varchar(2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COUNTRY_NAME | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REGION_ID    | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

Comment: If you run `select * from dup_countries` you will see that in the 1st case the table is empty and in the 2nd case it contains all the rows of `countries`.

Comment: i now understood their differences. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can of course check the documentation ([CREATE TABLE ... LIKE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-like.html), [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html)) but there're two main differences:

- `CREATE TABLE LIKE` creates an empty table, while `CREATE TABLE SELECT` inserts selected rows.
- `CREATE TABLE LIKE` copies source table definitions, indexes included, while
  `CREATE TABLE SELECT` figures out column types from actual data found (you don't necessarily have a source table to begin with, it can be any kind of dynamically generated result-set) and also allows you set the types manually.

Comment: might check the documentation next time. thank you so much for citing their differences!

Answer (score 1):

We can Clone Table using two ways:

1. using Like
2. using As Select * from TableName.

1st Way:

**CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table;**
It inherits only basic definitions,null settings and default values.
But doesnt inherit indexes and auto increment definitions.
It copy just structure and data.

2nd Way:

**CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;**
Inherit all table definitions without Data.
If we wants Data,we can use
**INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;**

Comment: okay, i might just try this one. thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, when you decide on one. That will help others who read your question in future

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dup_countries LIKE countries;
```

is not equal to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dup_countries AS SELECT * FROM countries;
```

The main difference - 2nd query adds rows into newly created table whereas 1nd one creates empty table.

You may eliminate this difference by adding a condition to 2nd query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dup_countries AS SELECT * FROM countries WHERE FALSE;
```

Both 1st and 3rd query produces the same result - empty table.

But the differences exists nevertheless. **And they may be critical.**

1st query copies a lot of constructions into the table-copy. Indices. Constraints (including NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY...). Comments. And so on... And even generated columns definitions.

Whereas 2nd and 3rd queries creates "cleared" structure - only base properties are reproduced.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bbebd3667bd333f1ca55edfeac04ae8

PS. And none query copies foreign keys and triggers.